# Awesome WM will not show any external devices (Arch)

Tags: mount, arch-linux, awesome-wm, external-drive

Things went fine with the Arch installation. I installed nautilus once I got into the GUI, but when I plugged in my external USB, it would not show up anywhere. I come from Ubuntu where there is a /media folder where all the USBs' and external drives go. There is non on mine new OS (but that is not the problem). How do I make it so that I can actually see and access drives. How do I make it so that it is automatically mounted in the /media folder I made.

Any response will help out greatly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the program you still need to install is gvfs. Nautilus uses that to mount your drive, not as soon as it's plugged in, but as soon as you try to access it. You should see an icon for your USB in the side pane. When you click it, nautilus will mount it to /run/media//, (no longer to /media).

Take a look at this for more info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Storage_Devices